# How to connect iPhone to Internet by USB cable?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, iphone

I have a desktop computer and an iPhone. The WiFi here is too unstable, and cellular is expensive. However, the Ethernet connection to my computer is stable and fast.
I need to connect my iPhone to the Internet via USB cable, so I can enjoy stable and fast connection.
My iOS version is 10.3.1, which means jailbreak is unavailable.
**Note:** I have Bing'ed the Internet and find nothing useful. All the answers seem suspicious or useless at all.
Don't suggest me to buy anything. I don't accept solutions that need any payment.
Don't ask me to try anything else like a laptop or a WiFi router. I want to connect my iPhone to internet with **exactly** the computer with an Ethernet connection and a USB cable.

Comment: Just accept that this isn't going to happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's a clear understanding of ***how*** this technology works, and to say that you won't accept a solution if it requires any expense on your part is going to strongly limit your acceptable solutions.

Since you listed your only hardware as being your desktop computer with a wired ethernet connection, the data lightning-to-USB cable, and your iPhone, then the setup might imply that you want to use your desktop computer for either ICS or a network bridge. But, actually, I have this sneaking suspicion that you are talking about something entirely different which is USB reverse tethering. If you need further clarification on a network bridge or ICS, I could discuss it later but I don't think either will deliver the result that you're looking for. And, as I said before, what I believe you are asking for is USB reverse tethering. It's not a feature that either Android or iOS supports without root.

But, if you changed your mind about purchasing additional equipment, you could set up a wired ethernet connection without rooting your device. You would need the lightning-to-USB cable (which you have), the power adapter for your phone (which you have), a USB-to-ethernet adapter, and the Lightning-to-USB 3 Camera Adapter or a compatible powered USB hub.

Otherwise, it's really not possible to share an ethernet connection with your computer because your phone without root can not perform USB reverse tethering. It's only made possible through additional equipment because of the adapters, and the power-over-ethernet that is made available by connecting all of those adapters.

See also: [Required parts for connecting ethernet to phone](https://jacobsalmela.com/2016/04/09/use-wired-ethernet-on-your-ipad-or-iphone/)

Comment: I'm very disappointed at the fact. Perhaps I should apply for another job now.

Comment: I agree that this seems to be about reverse tethering, but I don't agree on it being only possible with jailbreak or root. For iOS, it seems like the functionality is natively supported since iOS 10, but requires a computer running macOS. On Android, there are several third-party solutions that support Windows, macOS and Linux computers.

Answer (score 9):

Actually it is possible. I'm working on a mac, so I'll provide you a solution for a mac computer.

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Sharing` -> `Internet sharing`

Choose where are you willing share the internet from (ie. Ethernet) and in `To computer using` find and check `iPhone USB`.

Once all set, check the tick for `Internet sharing` to turn it on.

Comment: Yes but how can you find the network on your phone?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This indeed works and very easy to setup. Tested on iOS 12.1.4 and OS X 10.14.3

Comment: This also can be easily done with Microsoft Windows, using the "[Internet Connection Sharing](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22internet+connection+sharing%22+windows+site%3Amicrosoft.com)" feature. See, e.g., [this article at Allthings.how](https://allthings.how/how-to-share-pc-internet-with-iphone-over-usb-cable/)